# Temporal Table SYSTEM_TIME Range Not Working

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2016, temporal-tables

I have a temporal table defined as:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[MyTable](
    [Id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [Name] [varchar](200) NOT NULL,
    [Description] [varchar](100) NULL,
    [CreatedOn] [datetime] NULL,
    [LastUpdatedOn] [datetime] NULL,
    [SysStartTime] [datetime2](7) GENERATED ALWAYS AS ROW START NOT NULL,
    [SysEndTime] [datetime2](7) GENERATED ALWAYS AS ROW END NOT NULL
 CONSTRAINT [PK_MyTable] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [Id] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY],
    PERIOD FOR SYSTEM_TIME ([SysStartTime], [SysEndTime])
) ON [PRIMARY]
WITH
(
SYSTEM_VERSIONING = ON ( HISTORY_TABLE = [dbo].[MyTable_History] )
)
```

and when I try to do a query like this:

```
SELECT * FROM MyTable FOR SYSTEM_TIME from '2020-08-18 00:00:00' to '2020-08-18 23:59:59'
```

I seem to get rows that are not in the range as well. For example,

```
Name1 Description1 2018-07-05 22:53:36.543 2020-03-17 16:25:44.707 2020-07-22 18:21:03.9662004 9999-12-31 23:59:59.9999999
```

`2020-07-22` is not in the range but why is it showing up?

Comment: Because that was one version of the row that was valid on August 18th? Maybe you have a different idea about how temporal data is supposed to work... what type of temporal query do you think _should_ make that row show up? If you expect to find rows that were *modified* on August 18th, that's something different (just use your `LastUpdatedOn` column).

Comment: @AaronBertrand I see. Are you saying when I use the query above the rows I see do NOT mean they were changed in that date/time range but only mean they were valid?

Comment: Correct. Temporal Tables allow you to look at the state of a table _at a point in time_ or _within a range of time_. Again, you have a `LastUpdatedOn` column, if you're looking for rows that were modified in a certain range, use that column.

Comment: @AaronBertrand Got it. Thanks.